# Signification du mot « désintérêt »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

> Il est toujours plus aisé de reconnaître ce qui vous appartient
>   que de comprendre votre voisin avec respect et désintérêt.

(Extrait de http://www.carnetlecture.com/essais/lidee-europeenne-selon-stefan-zweig/)

Quelle est la signification du mot **désintérêt** dans le contexte ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le désintérêt est l'absence d'intérêt. Ici « intérêt » se réfère à la définition suivante :

> Intérêt personnel, attachement égoïste à ce qui est avantageux pour soi sans égard pour autrui, en partic. dans le domaine pécuniaire. ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt))

Regarder son voisin avec intérêt, ça serait le regarder en ayant son propre intérêt en tête, en se demandant ce que le voisin peut nous apporter voire même ce qu'on peut lui prendre. Ça ressemble par exemple à « agir par intérêt », où l'on agit uniquement en considérant son propre intérêt et pas celui des autres. Au contraire, « comprendre son voisin avec désintérêt », c'est le comprendre sans être égoïste.